# Eclipse - Not able to run TestNG tests

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, testng

I am using Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 and have installed TestNG plug-in for it but am not able to run TestNG program as TestNG console is displaying below error.

> "**Plug-in org.testng.eclipse was unable to load class
>   org.testng.eclipse.ui.TestRunnerViewPart.**"

I am not able to resolve this even after reinstalling the Eclipse and creating projects in new workspace.

Comment: Which version of TestNG are you using?

Comment: @peetya -  TestNG version is - 6.9.5.201505260426

Comment: and from where/how did you download it?

Comment: I have installed through "Install New Software" option of "Help" menu in Eclipse. Given the TestNG download url as "http://beust.com/eclipse".

Comment: Give a try to install it from this link: http://beust.com/eclipse1.

Comment: Not able to install from beust.com/eclipse1 since it support only older version of Eclipse IDE's.